# Displaying field value in new column in users view on wordpress

Tags: user-meta

I have never developed a Wordpress site to this level before.

One of my plugins introduces security questions for the user at registration time. I only have one question.

In the backend, when admin role logged in, I want to display this meta data in a new column on screen in the users view.

So:

1. Display extra column heading ‘Security Answer’
2. For each user:

   `$data = get_user_meta ( $user_id);
   If $data[‘meta_key’] is ‘Xxxxx’
       $answer = $data['meta_value'][0];
       Display answer in new column`

I don’t know how to go about this level customisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function to register a new column in the users table:

```
function users_custom_columns( $column ) {
    $column['security_answer'] = 'Security Answer';
    return $column;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'users_custom_columns' );
```

And this function to display the new custom column:

```
function display_users_custom_columns( $val, $column_name, $user_id ) {

    switch ($column_name) {

        case 'security_answer' :
            return get_user_meta( $user_id, 'meta_key', true);
        default:

    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', 'display_users_custom_columns', 10, 3 );
```

You can place the code in your functions.php or in a custom plugin.

Comment: I am trying now. Had to add a ' to here: 'Security Answer'. Will update you.

Comment: I have a column, but nothing is displayed in the cells.

Comment: have you changed the 'meta_key' with the name of the meta key in this line:
get_user_meta( $user_id, 'meta_key', true)

Comment: I had to use `security_check` for the parameter passed in. But the output I am getting is "Array". How do we get the first item in the array?

Comment: try $meta_value = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'meta_key', true);
echo $meta_value[0];

Comment: No. Doesn't work. Sorry.

Comment: Looking at the database, the value of meta_value is like: `a:1:{i:16;s:19:"abcde";}`

Comment: How are you saving the meta value?
It seems like it's encoded as a json string and you have to decode it first.

Comment: I don't save the meta_value myself. That is all the plugin I am using. But I was hoping to atleast display the json string because I can easily see the answer component. But all I am getting is a empty cell.

Comment: Sorted! I use `print_r($meta_value);` then I could see what the index was in the array. All working and it shows just the answer. Sweet!